# Switch to another running process

Tags: c#, process, switch-statement

Can someone please explain how I would go about switching to another running program via C#?

For example if i create a new application with a button event - i would like to use the button to say call an open application like internet explorer or word.

I know how to start applications but not quite sure how to call them when they are already running.

This is what have been working on so far:

```
    if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("ExternalApplication").Length >= 1)
    {
        foreach (Process ObjProcess in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("ExternalApplication"))
        {
            ActivateApplication(ObjProcess.Id);
            Interaction.AppActivate(ObjProcess.Id);
            SendKeys.SendWait("~");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call them when they are already running"? Are you just trying to bring them into focus on the user's computer? Are you trying to invoke some API for the running application?

Comment: Are you sure you want to switch to the other app (as opposed to, say, embedding a browser control in your app)?  Some context would help here.
If you really want to switch, what I think you want is the (COM) Interop APIs (Google is your friend :) -- that should allow you to switch to the app (if already running) or launch (if not).

Comment: Im just trying to switch to another running application. Dont matter what the app is - i just want to be able to do it by a button event. From what i understand you can call it from the process name that appears in task manager. Its a c# winform i working in.

Answer (score 4):

I had to solve a similar problem, and I had to do some pInvoking to get it done.  See code below.

```
delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);
public static class WindowEnumerator
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

    public static IDictionary<IntPtr, string> GetOpenWindowsFromPID(int processID)
    {
        IntPtr hShellWindow = GetShellWindow();
        Dictionary<IntPtr, string> dictWindows = new Dictionary<IntPtr, string>();

        EnumWindows(delegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
                    {
                        if (hWnd == hShellWindow) return true;
                        if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

                        int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
                        if (length == 0) return true;

                        uint windowPid;
                        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out windowPid);
                        if (windowPid != processID) return true;

                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(length);
                        GetWindowText(hWnd, stringBuilder, length + 1);
                        dictWindows.Add(hWnd, stringBuilder.ToString());
                        return true;
                    }, 0);

        return dictWindows;
    }
}

...

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

...

Process yourProcess = ???;

Dictionary<IntPtr, string> windows = (Dictionary<IntPtr, string>)WindowEnumerator.GetOpenWindowsFromPID(yourProcess.Id);
IntPtr mainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> pair in windows)
{
    if (pair.Value.ToUpperInvariant() == "Main Window Title")
    {
        mainWindowHandle = pair.Key;
        break;
    }
}

if (mainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    if (IsIconic(mainWindowHandle))
    {
        ShowWindow(mainWindowHandle, 9);
    }
    SetForegroundWindow(mainWindowHandle);
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the following errors - i have missed something simple?

The name 'notepad' does not exist in the current context

The name 'WindowEnumerator' does not exist in the current context

Im using the following.

using System;
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

Comment: I apologize. I ended up moving my WindowEnumerator logic into it's own class.  Please see code above.

Comment: @jonfen - I know this is old question and answer, but couple of minutes ago I found Your code and it saved me probably couple of hours trying to solve this by my own. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

below code worked for me

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SingleInstanceWindow
{
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var me = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        var arrProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(me.ProcessName);
        if (arrProcesses.Length > 1)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(arrProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle);
            return;
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

above code doesn't work if window is minimized

code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);
```

usage:

```
SwitchToThisWindow(arrProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following but i dont think have defined the process name correctly on line 31.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test_winform_app
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Process yourProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

Dictionary<IntPtr, string> windows = (Dictionary<IntPtr, string>)WindowEnumerator.GetOpenWindowsFromPID(yourProcess.Id);
IntPtr mainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> pair in windows)
{
    if (pair.Value.ToUpperInvariant() == "Main Window Title")
    {
        mainWindowHandle = pair.Key;
        break;
    }
}

if (mainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    if (IsIconic(mainWindowHandle))
    {
        ShowWindow(mainWindowHandle, 9);
    }
    SetForegroundWindow(mainWindowHandle);
}
        }

        delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);
        public static class WindowEnumerator
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

            [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
            private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

            [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
            private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

            [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
            private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
            private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
            private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

            public static IDictionary<IntPtr, string> GetOpenWindowsFromPID(int processID)
            {
                IntPtr hShellWindow = GetShellWindow();
                Dictionary<IntPtr, string> dictWindows = new Dictionary<IntPtr, string>();

                EnumWindows(delegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
                {
                    if (hWnd == hShellWindow) return true;
                    if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

                    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
                    if (length == 0) return true;

                    uint windowPid;
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out windowPid);
                    if (windowPid != processID) return true;

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(length);
                    GetWindowText(hWnd, stringBuilder, length + 1);
                    dictWindows.Add(hWnd, stringBuilder.ToString());
                    return true;
                }, 0);

                return dictWindows;
            }
        }
    }
}
```